# maas-enlisting-node login:

Tags: maas

I have successfully setup MAAS and openstack autopilot on my home network and I am trying to repeat the process at work.

maas controller is ready and waiting.
node computer pxe boots, receives an IP on the correct network and very quickly reaches the "maas-enlisting-node login:" phase. But here is where it stops. I have left the node for more than 30 minutes and it never gets past this stage.

Can I look at or post here a logfile and see what might be going wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Kindest regards

JK

Answer (score 0):

Since you are seeing the `maas-enlisting-node` prompt, I assume the node is enlisted, but has not yet been commissioned. When the node enlists, MAAS will capture basic information about it, such as its MAC address, and it will become available for editing. It will show up in the MAAS Web UI as `New` in this case.

The next step after enlisting the node is to ensure the power parameters are appropriately set up so that MAAS can power the machine on and off, and then commission the node.

After the node has been commissioned, you will see that the node is in `Ready` state, and Ubuntu can be deployed - either by Autopilot, or otherwise.

Comment: "Since you are seeing the maas-enlisting-node prompt, I assume the node is enlisted, but has not yet been commissioned." This is not true. The first time you see the message, the node does a bit more in order to enlist and then powers down. After the power down you see the node in the web interface as New. I never get the node in the web interface. It never enlists.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you see the node as `New`, or do you not see it at all? Can you check `/var/log/maas/*` to see if there are any clues? (the enlisting node should contact the MAAS server) It may be that the cluster controller does not know the proper URL to the region. Try running `dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller` and make sure it is correct. (As noted [here in the docs](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html#configuring-the-cluster-controller).)

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear. I do not see the node in the web ui.

Comment: One thing I have noticed, is that I can't get it to work in a dual network environment. Because I'm doing everything in a virtual KVM world, when I have two networks (public,private) the node never enlists. If I remove the public network the node enlists. Very strange! The dual network setup is kind of a requirement for me so I have to keep trying. I checked the logfiles you mentioned but nothing stands out to me. Would the output from one or all of them, help you help me?

Comment: When you ran `dpkg-reconfigure` on the cluster controller, did you make sure the configured URL is a URL that is reachable from the MAAS nodes on the private network? Did you ensure that when configuring your cluster interface, a default gateway is set, so that the nodes can speak to the MAAS server even if they are not on the same network?