# MAAS unable to to keep Node details under MAAS nodes

Tags: maas

Ubuntu 14.04.4 --- MAAS 1.9.1+bzr4543-0ubuntu1 (trusty1)

I have a Machine that PXE Boot and getting the console messages below

```
Start PXE over IPV4
Booting under MAAS direction
..........
....Bunch of Lines....
.....................
Starting Load Fallback graphics devices ..............[OK]
Starting Load Fallback graphics devices ..............[fail]  ----> This is the Only Fail
....................................
.............
..............
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
sjc-os-controller1 login: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at .......
Generating Locales 
.........
Generation Complete
...........
....Bunch of Lines....
...............
```

Then the PXE boot machine/node powers off

No Node present under MASS GUI under Nodes 
0 Nodes | 0 Device

MAAS --> Nodes --> Add Machine
If i try to add machine with its MAC Address ..... i then get status:(=Failed Commissioning)

Qs: Is there a Log that i can look into to check the root cause and fix the failure and commission nodes in MAAS.......Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Logs can be found here `/var/log/maas/maas.log` The documentation for  [automatic discovery](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.9/nodes.html#automatic-discovery) describes the process that should happen:

> With nodes set to boot from a PXE image, they will start, look for a
>   DHCP server, receive the PXE boot details, boot the image, contact the
>   MAAS server and shut down.

It looks like the server was able to connect to the DHCP server and receive a boot image but wasn't able to communicate back so make sure you have configured your [Cluster Controller](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.9/cluster-configuration.html#cluster-configuration) correctly and have added an [SSH Key](http://wiki.cloudbase.it/maas#ssh_keys).

Comment: Cool.... Thank you.... 
There no messages in  /var/log/maas/maas.log for the machine/node that i PXE boot...but when i add  Machine with MAC in MAAS ...i tail the maas.log below
 Error when checking power state: ('UNHANDLED', 'Unknown Error [ahs-maas-1:pid=576:cmd=PowerQuery:ask=9e]')
 Unable to determine power state.
[ERROR] Power state could not be queried: unknown url type: nuova
 [ERROR]: Failed to refresh power state: unknown url type: nuova
DHCP looks ok ......maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 1 DHCP leases to region controller.

Comment: To keep things tidy just update your question with this new information along with what Power Type you are using and confirm you have added a SSH key.

Comment: SSH keys are added for the user that i use to login to Ubuntu....Used Cisco UCS Manager and the errors previously reported...Also used for testing purpose wake-on-lan option and it timed out

Comment: Sounds like a networking issues, does the node you PXE boot contain more than one network interfaces as this could [complicate things](http://askubuntu.com/questions/742001/maas-enlisting-node-login#comment1107646_743345)? Double check the Cluster Controller can communicate with the Region Controller and they have been configured to meet the [network requirements](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.9/cluster-configuration.html#network-requirements)

Comment: yes the PXE node has two interfaces eth0 on a different VLAN and eth1 which is on the same VLAN as eth1 of MAAS.....Although the network requirement looks ok b/w Cluster-Region controller but i am getting error in cluster.d log 2016-04-19 14:35:08-0700 [Uninitialized] Region not available: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused. (While requesting RPC info at http://192.168.120.135/MAAS/rpc/).  What steps can i take to confirm if both the Cluster and Region are working fine....Currently the only zone that i have is the default......

Comment: Also under Clusters i only see Cluster master - status enabled - images synced.....should there be a Cluster and region controller.....as well.....

Comment: I am not all that familiar with diagnosing network issues but you could try disabling one of the network points in the BIOS and keeping the network point managed by MAAS or any of the other ideas suggested in the answer posted by @zalmarge

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had to deal with servers having the same interesting feature/bug. Two network interfaces that were recognized as eth0 and eth1 in BIOS, switched their positions when booting to Linux. I mean an interface that was eth0 in BIOS became eth1, and eth1 – eth0.

You could leave the interface eth1 (which you said is on the same network as MAAS) and disable eth0 in BIOS. If there's no option in BIOS for switching off eth0, then you'll have to boot into some Live Linux distro and check the order of NICs.

Or you just try switching cables and see if that helps. If it does, then you do have a problem with NIC ordering and you have just solved your problem :-)